# Integer Radix, what exactly does it mean?

Tags: java

`Integer.valueOf("10", 2)` what should this return and why? I thought a radix was the base of a number but I am confused as to what this function is doing exactly with different values.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are confused on?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oops I am thinking about it backwards, I was expecting it to convert base 10 to base 2, not the other way around. Is there a built in java function to convert the base the opposite direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert the base the opposite direction"? The method above converts a String to an int. There are several format methods that convert an int to a String, and I'm sure that you're already familiar with some of them. The API would have answered your original question in seconds btw.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was expecting it to convert 10 to 1010 and I tried a bunch of random numbers and had a brain freeze. Forgot to think about it backwards.

Comment: The function means [convert from "10" as a radix-2 string into int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Underlying representation of integer typse are always binary, so you can't specify it anyway

Comment: if you want 10 to 1010 then simply use `Integer.valueOf("10", 10)` or `Integer.valueOf("10")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every number representation requires to know the radix or base to be converted to a real value.

The radix identifies the "alphabet" of the digits like you thought. Indeed you could have

- radix `2` - alphabet `0, 1` (binary number)
- radix `8` - alphabet `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` (octal number)
- radix `10` - decimal number

and so on. But nothing prevents you from having a "radix-9" number with an alphabet of `0..8` so that `381` would be `3*radix^2 + 8*radix^1 + 1*radix^0`.

Comment: I see, the reason I was confused is because I was expecting it to do the opposite. Is there a built in Java function to convert a base 10 number to to any base I want? Or does it only go the opposite direction?

Comment: @CodeCamper `Integer.toString(956, 3)` converts the base 10 number `956` to base 3. It doesn't do any base you want (the maximum is 36).